# How to shift image while using background-position css

Tags: html, css, background, background-position

To style the scrollbar on my page, I used to have the following CSS. It gave me the perfect result and aligned the image in the center of the scrollbar.

```
background: #3395d2 url('img/thumb.png') no-repeat center;
border-radius: 8px;
border: 1px solid #004c98;
```

However, I then I took the background and created a sprite using other small images on my page. Then to style the image on the scrollbar again, I used the following CSS. However, this time it was not aligned in the center.

```
background: #3395d2 url('img/small-images.png') no-repeat center;
border-radius: 8px;
border: 1px solid #004c98;
background-position: 0 -702px;
```

How can I edit my code so that the image still aligns in the middle of the scrollbar, despite being in a sprite?

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/g5Fz6/)

Comment: can you provide a fiddle displaying the problem?

Comment: @Vector http://jsfiddle.net/g5Fz6/ The top text box is the before, and the bottom one is the current.

Comment: Essentially you'll have to set the `background-size` to where only the part you want is showing. Not sure what that is, you'll have to play around with it

Answer (score 2):

first of all, the `center` doesn't even matter once you redefine `background-position`.

```
background: #3395D2 url('http://s21.postimg.org/3ymz2gr8n/small_images.png') no-repeat center;
```

is the same as saying:

```
background-color: #3395D2;
background-image: url('http://s21.postimg.org/3ymz2gr8n/small_images.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
```

so when you say

```
background-position: 0 -702px;
```

after saying

```
background-position: center;
```

you are overriding it.

that said, you have another issue. just because it's a sprite doesn't mean CSS treats each image *in* your sprite like a separate image. if you align it vertically, you will see the other images in your sprite. i would suggest making the sprite horizontal instead of vertical, then adjusting the `background-position-x` (the `0` in your current code) to select the image you want in your sprite, and `background-position-y` (the `-702px` in your current code) to center it vertically on the scroll bar.